# Problems with simple bash script

Tags: bash

I have the following task:

Write a program that, given a directory as argument, makes a tar file compressed with gzip and which name should be in the form "dirNameYYYY-MM-DD.tar.gz". If said file exists, it should return an error message.

What I tried:

```
#!/bin/bash
dir=$1
tarName=$dir`date '+%Y-%m-%d'`.tar.gz
if [ -e $tarName]
then
echo "That file already exists."
else
tar -cvz $HOME/$tarName '/'$dir *
fi
```

Why is this not working? Any suggestions on how I could fix it?

Comment: This furiously looks like homework, but whatever: Shouldn't it be `${dir}/*` at the last line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
#!/bin/bash
dir=$1
tarName=$(basename $dir)$(date '+%Y-%m-%d').tar.gz
if [ -e $tarName ]
then
  echo "That file already exists."
else
  tar -cvzf $tarName $dir 
fi
```

Comment: Add a space before `]`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. What does the $(date) do vs `\`date\``?

Comment: In general, is the same. But Posix and with a syntax that usually causes less errors.